# LINQ return all records and groupby on MVC5 Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

My query returns a list of people who match a specific position. I want it to return a list of all positions, even if there are no people who match the position. The reason I'm joining on people is because I need the count of "Assigned" which is a dynamically added count field that match the position. But if there are no people who match the position I want it to still return the billeted position but want "Assigned" to be set to 0.

```
    dynamic query = (from a in db.Positions
                     join b in db.People 
                     on new { 
                         a.GradeId, 
                         a.SeriesId, 
                         a.CompanyId, 
                         a.PaybandId }
                     equals new { 
                         b.GradeId, 
                         b.SeriesId, 
                         b.CompanyId, 
                         b.PaybandId } into ab
                     from k in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join c in db.Grades on k.GradeId equals c.Id
                     join d in db.Series on k.SeriesId equals d.Id
                     join e in db.Companies on k.CompanyId equals e.Id
                     join p in db.Paybands on k.PaybandId equals p.Id
                     group a by new { CompanyName = e.Name, 
                         GradeName = c.Name, 
                         SeriesName = d.Name, 
                         PaybandName = p.Name, 
                         a.Authorized } into f
                     select new { Company = f.Key.CompanyName, 
                         Grade = f.Key.GradeName, 
                         Series = f.Key.SeriesName, 
                         Payband = f.Key.PaybandName, 
                         Authorized = f.Key.Authorized, 
                         Assigned = f.Count() }).AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.ToExpando());
```

Another issue I'm facing is that on the razor page, the Company is repeating. I'm needing the company heading to show up only once per company but want all positions to be listed below it.

Here's the view screenshot and razor script:
[image: Razor View Screenshot]

```
@model  IEnumerable<dynamic>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-1"></th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Grade</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Series</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Payband</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Authorized</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Assigned</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (dynamic item in Model)
    {
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="panel-bg" colspan="6">@item.Company</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">@item.Grade</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">@item.Series</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">@item.Payband</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">@item.Authorized</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">@item.Assigned</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT (Added Positions.cs class at request)

```
namespace CPR.Models
{
using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class Positions
    {
        public Positions()
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int SeriesId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int GradeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PaybandId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Authorized { get; set; }

        public virtual Companies Companies { get; set; }

        public virtual Series Series { get; set; }

        public virtual Grades Grades { get; set; }

        public virtual Paybands Paybands { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your Position class?

Comment: @MichaelBurns - added per your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly change the logic in you query to count earlier, and then things will become a bit easier. Please see the comments in the code snippet below:

```
            ...

            from a in db.Positions
                 join b in db.People 
                 on new { 
                     a.GradeId, 
                     a.SeriesId, 
                     a.CompanyId, 
                     a.PaybandId }
                 equals new { 
                     b.GradeId, 
                     b.SeriesId, 
                     b.CompanyId, 
                     b.PaybandId } into ab
                 from k in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 // you want to count the number of people per position here

                 group k by new { a.GradeId, a.SeriesId, a.CompanyId, a.PaybandId, a.Authorized } into g
                 select new { g.Key.GradeId, g.Key.SeriesId, g.Key.CompanyId, g.Key.PaybandId, g.Authorized, Count = g.Count(p => p != null) } into counts

                 // at this point you have position info AND people count per position
                 // next, you can do the remaining joins...

                 join c in db.Grades on counts.GradeId equals c.Id
                 join d in db.Series on counts.SeriesId equals d.Id
                 join e in db.Companies on counts.CompanyId equals e.Id
                 join p in db.Paybands on counts.PaybandId equals p.Id

                 // ... and select full data set, including person count, required for the view

                 select new { 
                    CompanyName = e.Name,
                    GradeName = c.Name,
                    SeriesName = d.Name, 
                    PaybandName = p.Name,
                    counts.Authorized,
                    Assigned = counts.Count
                 } into full

                 // one more step here that will help to tackle your second problem (grouping by company name in the view)
                 // you want your data coming into the view be grouped by company name 

                 group full by full.CompanyName into groupByCompany

                 select new CompanyInfo { CompanyName = groupByCompany.Key, CompanyItems = groupByCompany.Select(i => new CompanyItem { GradeName = i.GradeName, SeriesName = i.SeriesName, PaybandName = i.PaybandName, Authorized = i.Authorized, Assigned = i.Assigned }).ToList() }

                ...
```

Then in the view you'll need to create 2 `@foreach` loops instead of one. The first, outer one, will loop over the collection above and render a row with the company name once, while the other, inner one, will loop over the `CompanyItems` property of each item in the collection and render a row per item under the company name row.

Also, your generated HTML is not 100% valid as there are multiple `thead` tags which is [not allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3). Here's an edited version:

```
...
@model IEnumerable<CompanyInfo>

<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-1"></th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Grade</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Series</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Payband</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Authorized</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Assigned</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (CompanyInfo item in Model)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr class="company-name">
                <th class="panel-bg" colspan="6">@item.CompanyName</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (CompanyItem companyItem in item.CompanyItems)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">@companyItem.Grade</td>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">@companyItem.Series</td>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">@companyItem.Payband</td>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">@companyItem.Authorized</td>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">@companyItem.Assigned</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    }
</table>

...
```

To use a strongly-typed view model, add these two classes:

```
class CompanyInfo
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyItem> CompanyItems { get; set; }
}

class CompanyItem
{
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string SeriesName { get; set; }
    public string PaybandName { get; set; }
    public bool Authorized { get; set; }
    public int Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

and then update the code with accordance to the updates above.

Comment: Amazing, thorough answer. With your implementation, I'm getting a couple of errors though. 1. The name 'a' does not exist in the current context, and 2. 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Count'. select new { 
                    CompanyName = e.Name,
                    GradeName = c.Name,
                    SeriesName = d.Name, 
                    PaybandName = p.Name,
                    a.Authorized, // <---- error 1
                    Assigned = counts.Count() // <---- error 2
                 } into full

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Fixed them, please see the updated code. Basically, `Assigned = counts.Count()` should've been `Assigned = counts.Count`; and as for `a.Authorized`, it should've been included into the 1st group by and the re-used from there. Also, please note the use of the `class="company-name"` attr in the view. It's needed to style the company name rows with CSS since we got rid of the multiple `thead`s.

Comment: One last thing, on the view, replaced everything on the page with your code and passing into the view @model IEnumerable<dynamic>. I've gone through everything and with the final select in the dynamic query, it should contain "CompanyName", but getting an error of: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CompanyName' on the view. Any ideas?

Comment: wrapped the dynamic query in () and added .AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.ToExpando()) to the end, now I'm getting: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Grade' on: <td class="col-sm-2">@companyItem.Grade</td>

Comment: This is due to the combination of dynamic model and anonymous type being used as model. At runtime anonymous model is treated as an object, and objects don't have the properties we're trying to access. So here it's best to use a strongly-typed view model. I'll update the code now.

Comment: Braddah, you're awesome. Mahalo! The anonymous types and dynamic models always have confused me. I look forward to the update. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! See the updated code. You'll need to add two classes, update the final `select` in the query, and also update the view. Let me know if there are any other erorrs.

Comment: There were a couple of small changes I had to make here and there and a missing .Key. but the solution is rock solid and I appreciate all the time and help with getting this working. I understand it so much more with the way you did it, and will help me in the long run. Thanks again, bro! Well earned bounty! (can't award it until 17 hrs from now though)

Answer (score -1):

> "I want it to return a list of all positions, even if there are no
>   people who match the position."

**as you said** that, you should simply do next (edit this part):

before :

```
from a in db.Positions
join b in db.People
```

after :

```
from a in db.Positions
left join b in db.People
```

As you can see I applied `left join`, because The SQL `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table. This means that if the ON clause matches 0 (zero) records in the right table; the join will still return a row in the result, but with NULL in each column from the right table.

This means that a left join returns all the values from the left table, plus matched values from the right table or NULL in case of no matching join predicate.

I hope this helped to you,
Cheers

Comment: "left join" is not valid LINQ syntax, unfortunately, otherwise this would be much more simple :)